# illegal start of type error about my code

Tags: java, list, generics, diamond-operator

While I am creating a load , my program gives below error ;

```
D:\views\UniqueAcctStorageRuleNameValidator.java:34: illegal start of type
List<String> listOfAcctStorageRuleNameAsArray =
    new ArrayList<>(listOfAcctStorageRuleName.size());
```

Here is the code;

```
public class FKAcctStorageRuleNameValidator extends AbstractAnnotationCheck<FKAcctStorageRuleName>{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private SpecbookValidatorManager specBookValidator;   

   @Override
   public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object valueToValidate,
           OValContext context, Validator validator) throws OValException {
      if (valueToValidate == null) return true;

      specBookValidator = SpecbookValidatorManagerImpl.getInstance();

      List<SpecbookAcctStorageRule> listOfAcctStorageRuleName = specBookValidator.getAcctStorageRuleList();

      List<String> listOfAcctStorageRuleNameAsArray = new ArrayList<>(listOfAcctStorageRuleName.size());
      for (SpecbookAcctStorageRule specbookAcctStorageRule : listOfAcctStorageRuleName) {
         listOfAcctStorageRuleNameAsArray.add(specbookAcctStorageRule.getName());
      }

      return ListUtil.containsIgnoreCase((String) valueToValidate, listOfAcctStorageRuleNameAsArray);
   }
}
```

Comment: which jdk are u using? Java SE 7 and later, you can use diamond <>..Kindly check your java compiler version.

Comment: You create an `ArrayList` of *what*? Don't generics in Java need a type?

Comment: @iMBMT I am using Java SE 6. When I give the parameter to the diamond, the issue is resolved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s likely that you are using the JDK a version which is lower than 7. It doesn't know what [the diamond `<>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) is.

Changing to the following will solve the issue:

```
new ArrayList<String>(listOfAcctStorageRuleName.size());
```

*Of course, you are free to download a newer Java version to use all convenient features that are not allowed in the previous ones.*

Comment: Thank you for the information.I am using JDK 6 and when I give the diamon type as String as per your answer, the issue is resolved.